# Random Panel Color in Listener for button only works once

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, jlabel

My Listener is only executing the method `changeColor()` once.

Tried different versions of random color creators

Code:

```
// Java program to create a blank text
// field of definite number of columns.
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    // JTextField
    static JTextField textField;

    // JFrame
    static JFrame frame;

    // JButton
    static JButton button;

    // label to display text
    static JLabel label;

    static JPanel panel;

    // main class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create a new frame to stor text field and button
        frame = new JFrame("textfield");

        // create a label to display text
        label = new JLabel("nothing entered");

        // create a new button
        button = new JButton("submit");

        // create a panel
        panel = new JPanel();

        // create an object of the text class
        Main te = new Main();

        // addActionListener to button
        button.addActionListener(te);

        // create an object of JTextField with 16 columns
        textField = new JTextField(16);

        // add buttons and textfield to label and then to panel
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        label.setOpaque(true);

        // add panel to frame
        frame.add(panel);

        // set the size of frame
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        frame.show();
    }

    // if the button is pressed
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
    {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
        if (s.equals("submit")) {

            // set the text of the label to the text of the field
            if(textField.getText().equals("hue")) {
                panel.setBackground(changeColor());
            }

            label.setText(textField.getText());

            // set the text of field to blank
            textField.setText(" ");
        }
    }
    public Color changeColor() {
        Color randomColor = new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000));
        return randomColor;
    }
}
```

I want the program to create a new color over and over when typing "hue" in the textField an submitting with the button.
Sadly this works only one time.

Comment: The method `changeColor` works for me. Something else has to be wrong here. Is your if-statement entered everytime? Did you try to debug?

Comment: Did you check the random color? Is the method invoked as your expect? Does it return a different color as your expect?

Comment: @camickr well if i knew if it s invoked correctly, i wouldnt ask here. I really got no idea. It seems everything with an if statement in the actionPerformed Listener is only done once. The random colour alway is a different one and works fine. The issue seems to be that the if case is only gone through once

Comment: `I really got no idea.` - what do you mean you got no idea? Do you have any idea how do use System.out.println(...)? You add those statement in your methods to see if the method is executed when you expect it to be executed. So the first line of code in your actionPerformed() method could be `System.out.println("actionPerformed");` If you see the message you know the button click worked. You should see this message every time you click the button, not just the first.

Comment: `It seems everything with an if statement in the actionPerformed Listener is only done once` You can also display the value of your variables to see if they contain the value you expect. Then once you know what the values are you can determine why the if statement is or isn't executed. This is basic problem solving 101!

Comment: @camickr the colors do work out great... they are random. Thats not the issue, the variables all are as they should be in the range of (0 to 1)*256. How should i Sout a Color???

Comment: So that answer one question. If the colorChange() method is invoked, it returns a random Color. So the question is How many times is that method invoked??? Did you display the value of the actionCommand to make sure it is "Submit"? Did you display the text from the text field to make sure it is "hue"?

Comment: @camickr if you mean making sure the button title is submit and the text is hue; yes i did that

Comment: @camickr now i see... "" and " " are two seperate things... already ran into this a while ago! Thank you for yoour patience and explanation that made me learn fishing ;D

Answer (score 1):

At line `78` your calling:

```
textField.setText(" ");
```

I guess you want to call:

```
textField.setText("");
```

To really make your textfield empty. " " is not the same as ""

After the first time you press your button the textfield contains " ". If you are typing hue after that, the content of the textfield is " hue" and not "hue".

Therefore your if-statement is not `true` at `textField.getText().equals("hue")` and your method is not getting invoked.

Comment: How does this teach the OP basic debugging? Have you not read my comments to show him how to debug the logic flow to make sure it works the way it is expected? Telling him the problem doesn't help him solve the next problem. `If you give someone a fish they eat for a day. If you teach someone to fish they eat for life.`.

Comment: @camickr although im thankful to you Moritz, i guess camickr is right. I think it is important to not just show but teach! Camickr, since im now out of ideas, would you have a newby friendly task with swing to get started?

Comment: @camickr While I agree (strongly) with the 'teach a man to fish' philosophy, I've noted that many people object to using that approach on SO. Everybody see also the (peripherally) related: See [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)